# Access the scope value from the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm returning an object with a factory, but I can't access the scope value from the controller.

I just started with Angular, so I guess I overlooked something here.

```
app.factory('Jobs', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getJobs : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/jobs');
        }
    }
}]);

app.controller('JobsController', ['$scope', 'Jobs', function ($scope, Jobs) {

    Jobs.getJobs().success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.jobs = data;
    }).error(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    console.log($scope);
    // Returns Object with jobs: Array[89]

    console.log($scope.jobs);
    // Returns undefined
}]);
```

Comment: the interesting part of this question: why do we see the jobs array in the `console.log($scope);` call but not in the later `console.log($scope.jobs);`? Is `console.log` async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your promise has not been resolved yet when it hits your log statement. Move your log statement into the success callback, as I show below.

Note that I am using Angular's $log service instead of console.log.  Console.log can throw errors on IE if the console is not open.  $log handles that, plus allows you to use $log.info() and $log.debug() and such to better organize the logging levels.

```
app.factory('Jobs', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getJobs : function() {
            return $http.get('/api/jobs');
        }
    }

}]);

app.controller('JobsController', ['$scope', 'Jobs', '$log', function ($scope, Jobs, $log) {

    Jobs.getJobs()
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                $scope.jobs = data;
                $log.info($scope.jobs);
                // Should work now
            })
            .error(function (error) {
                    $log.info(error);
                });

    $log.info($scope);
    // Returns Object with jobs: Array[89]

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the call to the server is asynchronous, which means you will not get the value immediately after the call, but only in the success callback.

```
app.controller('JobsController', ['$scope', 'Jobs', function ($scope, Jobs) {
Jobs.getJobs()
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // now the call to the server is complete, and we have our data
            $scope.jobs = data;
            console.log($scope.jobs); // should show the data
        })
        .error(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });

console.log($scope);
// Returns Object with jobs: Array[89]

console.log($scope.jobs);
// Returns undefined because the call to the server isn't complete yet

}]);
```

Comment: If you want to do something when jobs is populated you can use a watch like this:
`$scope.$watch('jobs', function(val) {console.log(val);} )`

Comment: Also, the UI part is automatically re-rendered if `jobs` is being used there.

Comment: Can you explain the result of the first `console.log($scope);`?